# splitting long single words onto multiple lines without breaking links or html tags

Tags: jquery, html

I have the following line on my page in the `$(document).ready(function(){...}` It is done in ASP.NET

```
$("#standard-styling").html($("#standard-styling").text().replace(/([^\s-]{5})(?=[^\s-])/g, '$1&shy;'));
```

HTML:

```
<div id="standard-styling" class="description">
    <% Response.Write(Model.Description); %>
</div>
```

It works great for splitting long words onto multiple lines by adding a `-<br>` if the browser thinks it's necessary, and ignoring it if not (http://www.quirksmode.org/oddsandends/wbr.html). However, if the description contains a link, then the link will not show up as a hyperlink. Also, if there are line breaks, `<br />`  or other tags, they are likely to be broken and ignored as well. lastly, it is causing problems with encoded characters like `&lt;br /&gt;`. It is then seen as `<br />` and does insert a line break there.

Is there a better way to go about this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use css:

```
#standard-styling {
   word-wrap: break-word;
}
```

Or using jQuery:

```
$("#standard-styling").css('word-wrap', 'break-word');
```

**UPD:**

jQuery Example: [http://jsbin.com/ojoges/1/](http://jsbin.com/ojoges/2/)

CSS Example: http://jsbin.com/ojoges/